# How do I rename multiple selected layers in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, creative-cloud

I was searching this for a while, but didn't find a proper answer.  Does anybody know how to rename multiple selected layers at the same time?  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no native feature for renaming multiple layers, at least yet.

You can however start renaming a layer and use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to move to rename the next layer or <kbd>Shift+TAB</kbd> to rename the previous layer. This can be handy for smaller amount of layer renaming.

---

Pro tip regarding, I would guess all of these exentions and scripts:

In the bottom of [Group Layer Renaming script website](http://blog.kam88.com/en/group-layer-renaming-script.html) Matthew Rose mentions how you should use <kbd>cmd (in mac)</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl (in windows)</kbd> to select multiple groups instead of using <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

If you don't, you'll accidentally rename layers within the groups. This happens due to the way photoshop selects multiple layers when you hold down shift  <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

You can however get around it.

1. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple groups
2. Then hold <kbd>cmd (in mac)</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl (in windows)</kbd> and click one of the arrows on the left side of those groups. This expands every selected groups.

   - At  this point you can see that all the layers in between the groups are selected.
3. Click again ( while still holding cmd ). This closes the selected groups.

   - At this point, if you click again you can see that only the first level of selected groups are selected.
4. Now you're ready to rename just the first level of groups you've selected.

<sub>At step #2, you can actually double click the **first selected groups arrow** and jump to step #4.</sub>

---

## List of extensions and scripts:

#### [Renamy](http://www.renamy.com/)

- **Costs ~$10**
- Remembers layer names you've used and uses autocomplete when you start writing a new name.
- You can place the panel on top of your layers panel, for example. That gives it easy access. The only feature I feel like it's lacking is that you can't use a hotkey to focus in the input field. I would recommend using the last *script* listed in this post, if you want to use a hotkey.
- You can rename with consecutive numbers using: `Layer %NN` or `Layer %nn` to reverse the order.
- You can add and remove extensions and use regex.

[image]

#### [Adobe Layer Namer](https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/1680)

- **Free**
- Meant to be used in tandem with the Assets Generator in Photoshop CC, but at can potentially work with other export scripts and extensions.
- Only adds suffix with the extension and variables, which are mostly compatible with Assets Generator only. So if you need to randomly rename all layers "Mah Layers", this can't do that.

[image]

#### [Layrs Control](https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/1702)

- **Free**
- Layer name editor button basically just launches the below script.
- Contains more than one script

[image]

#### [Layer Name Editor script](http://www.ps-bridge-scripts.talktalk.net/)

- **Free**
- The extension listed above uses this script.
- You can set a hotkey so launch the scrip, which is very handy. The extension above doesn't have that feature.

Incase the link doesn't work, the script code can be found at the end of this post.

[image]

#### [Group Layer Renaming script](http://blog.kam88.com/en/group-layer-renaming-script.html)

- **Free**
- You can rename with consecutive numbers using: `Item #%n`
- You can set a hotkey so launch the script, which is very handy.

Incase the link doesn't work, the script code can be found at the end of this post.

[image]

---

---

---

### Code for the two scripts listed above.

**Layer Name Editor script**

```
// Layer Name Editor.jsx
#target Photoshop

app.bringToFront();main();
function main(){if(!documents.length)return;var selLayers=getSelectedLayersIdx();var selIdxNames=[];for(var s in selLayers)selIdxNames.push([[Number(selLayers[s])],[getLayerNameByIndex(Number(selLayers[s]))]]);selectAllLayers();var allLayers=getSelectedLayersIdx();var allIdxNames=[];for(var n in allLayers)allIdxNames.push([[Number(allLayers[n])],[getLayerNameByIndex(Number(allLayers[n]))]]);try{var win=new Window("dialog","Layer Name Editor");g=win.graphics;var myBrush=g.newBrush(g.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR,[.99,
.99,.99,1]);g.backgroundColor=myBrush;win.orientation="column";win.p1=win.add("panel",undefined,undefined,{borderStyle:"black"});win.p1.preferredSize=[380,100];win.g1=win.p1.add("group");win.g1.orientation="row";win.title=win.g1.add("statictext",undefined,"Layer Name Editor");win.title.alignment="fill";var g=win.title.graphics;g.font=ScriptUI.newFont("Georgia","BOLDITALIC",22);win.g5=win.p1.add("group");win.g5.orientation="row";win.g5.alignment="fill";win.g5.spacing=10;win.g5.rb1=win.g5.add("radiobutton",
undefined,"Use Selected Layers");win.g5.rb2=win.g5.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Use All Layers");win.g5.rb1.value=true;win.g10=win.p1.add("group");win.g10.orientation="row";win.g10.alignment="fill";win.g10.rb1=win.g10.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Prefix");win.g10.rb2=win.g10.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Suffix");win.g10.rb3=win.g10.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Remove");win.g10.rb4=win.g10.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Insert");win.g10.rb5=win.g10.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Replace");win.g10.rb5.value=
true;win.g15=win.p1.add("group");win.g15.orientation="row";win.g15.alignment="fill";win.g15.cb1=win.g15.add("checkbox",undefined,"Create Snapshot");win.stack=win.add("group");win.stack.spacing=10;win.stack.orientation="stack";win.stack.alignment="left";win.p2=win.stack.add("panel",undefined,undefined,{borderStyle:"black"});win.p2.preferredSize=[380,100];win.p2.visible=false;win.g200=win.p2.add("group");win.g200.orientation="row";win.g200.alignment="fill";win.g200.st1=win.g200.add("statictext",undefined,
"Prefix");win.g200.st1.preferredSize=[75,20];win.g200.et1=win.g200.add("edittext");win.g200.et1.preferredSize=[200,20];win.p3=win.stack.add("panel",undefined,undefined,{borderStyle:"black"});win.p3.preferredSize=[380,100];win.p3.visible=false;win.g300=win.p3.add("group");win.g300.orientation="row";win.g300.alignment="fill";win.g300.st1=win.g300.add("statictext",undefined,"Suffix");win.g300.st1.preferredSize=[75,20];win.g300.et1=win.g300.add("edittext");win.g300.et1.preferredSize=[200,20];win.p4=win.stack.add("panel",
undefined,undefined,{borderStyle:"black"});win.p4.preferredSize=[380,100];win.p4.visible=false;win.g400=win.p4.add("group");win.g400.orientation="row";win.g400.alignment="fill";win.g400.rb1=win.g400.add("radiobutton",undefined,"First(n) chars");win.g400.rb2=win.g400.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Last(n) chars");win.g400.rb3=win.g400.add("radiobutton",undefined,"Range From(n)");win.g400.rb1.value=true;win.g410=win.p4.add("group");win.g410.orientation="row";win.g410.alignment="fill";win.g410.et1=win.g410.add("edittext");
win.g410.et1.preferredSize=[50,20];win.g410.et1.onChanging=function(){if(this.text.match(/[^\-\.\d]/))this.text=this.text.replace(/[^\-\.\d]/g,"")};win.g410.st1=win.g410.add("statictext",undefined,"Number of Chars.");win.g410.et2=win.g410.add("edittext");win.g410.et2.preferredSize=[50,20];win.g410.et2.onChanging=function(){if(this.text.match(/[^\-\.\d]/))this.text=this.text.replace(/[^\-\.\d]/g,"")};win.g410.et2.visible=false;win.g410.st1.visible=false;win.g400.rb1.onClick=function(){win.g410.et2.visible=
false;win.g410.st1.visible=false};win.g400.rb2.onClick=function(){win.g410.et2.visible=false;win.g410.st1.visible=false};win.g400.rb3.onClick=function(){win.g410.et2.visible=true;win.g410.st1.visible=true};win.p5=win.stack.add("panel",undefined,undefined,{borderStyle:"black"});win.p5.preferredSize=[380,100];win.p5.visible=false;win.g500=win.p5.add("group");win.g500.orientation="row";win.g500.alignment="fill";win.g500.st1=win.g500.add("statictext",undefined,"Insert");win.g500.st1.preferredSize=[75,
20];win.g500.et1=win.g500.add("edittext");win.g500.et1.preferredSize=[200,20];win.g510=win.p5.add("group");win.g510.orientation="row";win.g510.alignment="fill";win.g510.st1=win.g510.add("statictext",undefined,"At position");win.g510.st1.preferredSize=[75,20];win.g510.et1=win.g510.add("edittext");win.g510.et1.preferredSize=[50,20];win.g510.et1.onChanging=function(){if(this.text.match(/[^\-\.\d]/))this.text=this.text.replace(/[^\-\.\d]/g,"")};win.p6=win.stack.add("panel",undefined,undefined,{borderStyle:"black"});
win.p6.preferredSize=[380,100];win.g600=win.p6.add("group");win.g600.orientation="row";win.g600.alignment="fill";win.g600.st1=win.g600.add("statictext",undefined,"Replace");win.g600.st1.preferredSize=[75,20];win.g600.et1=win.g600.add("edittext");win.g600.et1.preferredSize=[200,20];win.g610=win.p6.add("group");win.g610.orientation="row";win.g610.alignment="fill";win.g610.st1=win.g610.add("statictext",undefined,"With");win.g610.st1.preferredSize=[75,20];win.g610.et1=win.g610.add("edittext");win.g610.et1.preferredSize=
[200,20];win.g620=win.p6.add("group");win.g620.orientation="row";win.g620.alignment="fill";win.g620.cb1=win.g620.add("checkbox",undefined,"Global");win.g620.cb2=win.g620.add("checkbox",undefined,"Case Insensitive");win.g620.cb2.value=true;win.g10.rb1.onClick=function(){if(win.g10.rb1.value){win.p2.visible=true;win.p3.visible=false;win.p4.visible=false;win.p5.visible=false;win.p6.visible=false}};win.g10.rb2.onClick=function(){if(win.g10.rb2.value){win.p2.visible=false;win.p3.visible=true;win.p4.visible=
false;win.p5.visible=false;win.p6.visible=false}};win.g10.rb3.onClick=function(){if(win.g10.rb3.value){win.p2.visible=false;win.p3.visible=false;win.p4.visible=true;win.p5.visible=false;win.p6.visible=false}};win.g10.rb4.onClick=function(){if(win.g10.rb4.value){win.p2.visible=false;win.p3.visible=false;win.p4.visible=false;win.p5.visible=true;win.p6.visible=false}};win.g10.rb5.onClick=function(){if(win.g10.rb5.value){win.p2.visible=false;win.p3.visible=false;win.p4.visible=false;win.p5.visible=false;
win.p6.visible=true}};win.g1000=win.add("group");win.g1000.orientation="row";win.g1000.alignment="center";win.g1000.bu1=win.g1000.add("button",undefined,"Process");win.g1000.bu1.preferredSize=[150,30];win.g1000.bu2=win.g1000.add("button",undefined,"Cancel");win.g1000.bu2.preferredSize=[150,30];snapshotFlag=false;win.g1000.bu1.onClick=function(){if(win.g15.cb1.value&&!snapshotFlag){snapshotFlag=true;snapShot()}if(win.g10.rb1.value){if(win.g200.et1.text==""){alert("No Prefix has been entered!");return}win.close(0);
if(win.g5.rb1.value)var lList=selIdxNames;else var lList=allIdxNames;for(var z in lList)putLayerNameByIndex(Number(lList[z][0]),win.g200.et1.text.toString()+lList[z][11].toString())}if(win.g10.rb2.value){if(win.g300.et1.text==""){alert("No Suffix has been entered!");return}win.close(0);if(win.g5.rb1.value)var lList=selIdxNames;else var lList=allIdxNames;for(var z in lList)putLayerNameByIndex(Number(lList[z][0]),lList[z][12].toString()+win.g300.et1.text.toString())}if(win.g10.rb3.value){if(win.g400.rb1.value){if(win.g410.et1.text==
""){alert("No number has been entered!");return}if(Number(win.g410.et1.text)<1){alert("You can't remove zero characters!");return}win.close(0);if(win.g5.rb1.value)var lList=selIdxNames;else var lList=allIdxNames;for(var z in lList){var n=Number(win.g410.et1.text);var rex="/^(.{"+n+"})(.+)/";putLayerNameByIndex(Number(lList[z][0]),lList[z][13].toString().match(eval(rex))[2])}}if(win.g400.rb2.value){if(win.g410.et1.text==""){alert("No number has been entered!");return}if(Number(win.g410.et1.text)<1){alert("You can't remove zero characters!");
return}win.close(0);if(win.g5.rb1.value)var lList=selIdxNames;else var lList=allIdxNames;for(var z in lList){var n=Number(win.g410.et1.text);var rex="/(.+)(.{"+n+"}$)/";putLayerNameByIndex(Number(lList[z][0]),lList[z][14].toString().match(eval(rex))[1])}}if(win.g400.rb3.value){if(win.g410.et1.text==""||win.g410.et2.text==""){alert("No number has been entered!");return}if(Number(win.g410.et1.text)<1||Number(win.g410.et2.text)<1){alert("You can't remove zero characters!");return}win.close(0);if(win.g5.rb1.value)var lList=
selIdxNames;else var lList=allIdxNames;for(var z in lList){var n=Number(win.g410.et1.text);var r=Number(win.g410.et2.text);var rex="/^(.{"+n+"})(.{"+r+"})(.+)/";var parts=lList[z][15].toString().match(eval(rex));var newName=parts[1]+parts[3];putLayerNameByIndex(Number(lList[z][0]),newName)}}}if(win.g10.rb4.value){if(win.g500.et1.text==""){alert("You have not entered a string!");return}if(win.g510.et1.text==""){alert("You must enter a start number!");return}win.close(0);if(win.g5.rb1.value)var lList=
selIdxNames;else var lList=allIdxNames;for(var z in lList){var n=Number(win.g510.et1.text);if(n<1)n=1;var rex="/^(.{"+n+"})(.+)/";var parts=lList[z][16].toString().match(eval(rex));var newName=parts[1]+win.g500.et1.text.toString()+parts[2];putLayerNameByIndex(Number(lList[z][0]),newName)}}if(win.g10.rb5.value){if(win.g600.et1.text==""){alert("No replace value has been entered!");return}win.close(0);if(win.g620.cb1.value&&!win.g620.cb2.value)var changeFrom=new RegExp(win.g600.et1.text.toString(),"g");
if(!win.g620.cb1.value&&win.g620.cb2.value)var changeFrom=new RegExp(win.g600.et1.text.toString(),"i");if(win.g620.cb1.value&&win.g620.cb2.value)var changeFrom=new RegExp(win.g600.et1.text.toString(),"gi");if(!win.g620.cb1.value&&!win.g620.cb2.value)var changeFrom=new RegExp(win.g600.et1.text.toString());if(win.g5.rb1.value)var lList=selIdxNames;else var lList=allIdxNames;for(var z in lList)if(changeFrom.test(lList[z][17].toString()))putLayerNameByIndex(Number(lList[z][0]),lList[z][18].toString().replace(changeFrom,
win.g610.et1.text.toString()))}}}catch(e){alert(e+" - "+e.line)}win.center();win.show()}
function selectLayerByIndex(index,add){add=add==undefined?add=false:add;var ref=new ActionReference;ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),index);var desc=new ActionDescriptor;desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"),ref);if(add)desc.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("selectionModifier"),stringIDToTypeID("selectionModifierType"),stringIDToTypeID("addToSelection"));desc.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID("MkVs"),false);try{executeAction(charIDToTypeID("slct"),desc,DialogModes.NO)}catch(e){}}
function getLayerNameByIndex(idx){var ref=new ActionReference;ref.putProperty(charIDToTypeID("Prpr"),charIDToTypeID("Nm  "));ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),idx);return executeActionGet(ref).getString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  "))}
function selectAllLayers(){var desc29=new ActionDescriptor;var ref23=new ActionReference;ref23.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),charIDToTypeID("Ordn"),charIDToTypeID("Trgt"));desc29.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"),ref23);executeAction(stringIDToTypeID("selectAllLayers"),desc29,DialogModes.NO)}
function getSelectedLayersIdx(){var selectedLayers=new Array;var ref=new ActionReference;ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Dcmn"),charIDToTypeID("Ordn"),charIDToTypeID("Trgt"));var desc=executeActionGet(ref);if(desc.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID("targetLayers"))){desc=desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("targetLayers"));var c=desc.count;var selectedLayers=new Array;for(var i=0;i<c;i++)try{activeDocument.backgroundLayer;selectedLayers.push(desc.getReference(i).getIndex())}catch(e){selectedLayers.push(desc.getReference(i).getIndex()+
1)}}else{var ref=new ActionReference;ref.putProperty(charIDToTypeID("Prpr"),charIDToTypeID("ItmI"));ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),charIDToTypeID("Ordn"),charIDToTypeID("Trgt"));try{activeDocument.backgroundLayer;selectedLayers.push(executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID("ItmI"))-1)}catch(e){selectedLayers.push(executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID("ItmI")))}var vis=app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible;if(vis==true)app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible=false;var desc9=
new ActionDescriptor;var list9=new ActionList;var ref9=new ActionReference;ref9.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),charIDToTypeID("Ordn"),charIDToTypeID("Trgt"));list9.putReference(ref9);desc9.putList(charIDToTypeID("null"),list9);executeAction(charIDToTypeID("Shw "),desc9,DialogModes.NO);if(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible==false)selectedLayers.shift();app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible=vis}return selectedLayers}
function snapShot(){var desc9=new ActionDescriptor;var ref5=new ActionReference;ref5.putClass(charIDToTypeID("SnpS"));desc9.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"),ref5);var ref6=new ActionReference;ref6.putProperty(charIDToTypeID("HstS"),charIDToTypeID("CrnH"));desc9.putReference(charIDToTypeID("From"),ref6);desc9.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Usng"),charIDToTypeID("HstS"),charIDToTypeID("FllD"));executeAction(charIDToTypeID("Mk  "),desc9,DialogModes.NO)}
function putLayerNameByIndex(idx,name){if(idx==0)return;var desc=new ActionDescriptor;var ref=new ActionReference;ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),idx);desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"),ref);desc.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID("MkVs"),false);var nameDesc=new ActionDescriptor;nameDesc.putString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  "),name);desc.putObject(charIDToTypeID("T   "),charIDToTypeID("Lyr "),nameDesc);executeAction(charIDToTypeID("slct"),desc,DialogModes.NO);executeAction(charIDToTypeID("setd"),desc,DialogModes.NO)}
;
```

**Group Layer Renaming script**

```
// Group Layer Renaming script.jsx
@JSXBIN@ES@2.0@MyBbyBnADMiGbyBn0ABaiKbiLn0AEJiLnAEjzRjNjBjLjFiBjDjUjJjWjFiCjZiJj
OjEjFjYBfRCARBQzACfVzOjTjFjMjFjDjUjFjEiMjBjZjFjSjTDfCVzBjJEfBfFcfffJiOnASzGjUjN
jQiUjYjUFAVzDjUjYjUGfDnffJiPnASFAEXzHjSjFjQjMjBjDjFHfVFfARCFeChFjOCzBhNIXzGjMjF
jOjHjUjIJfVDfCVEfBnnffnffciRnAVzEjNjPjEjFKfEERBFeGjBjQjQjFjOjEfRBFeHjQjSjFjQjFj
OjEfRBFeHjSjFjQjMjBjDjFfRBnfEbiTn0ACJiTnABXzEjOjBjNjFLfXzLjBjDjUjJjWjFiMjBjZjFj
SMfXzOjBjDjUjJjWjFiEjPjDjVjNjFjOjUNfjzDjBjQjQOfCzBhLPnVFfAnnntDiUnACtbiWn0ACJiW
nABXLfXMfXNfjOfCPVFfAXLfXMfXNfjOfnnnfDiXnACtbiZn0ACJiZnABXLfXMfXNfjOfVFfAnfDian
ACtbicn0ACJicnABXLfXMfXNfjOfCPnVFfAnnntDidnACtAVEfBAXJfVDfCByBzBhcQAFE4B0AiAG4B
0AhAD40BhAK4C0AhAF40BiADCAzNjQjSjFjQjFjOjEiBjQjQjFjOjERAjBMjDbyBn0AGJjInASDAEjz
FiBjSjSjBjZSfntnftJjJnASzDjSjFjGTBEjzPiBjDjUjJjPjOiSjFjGjFjSjFjOjDjFUfntnftJjKn
AEXzNjQjVjUiFjOjVjNjFjSjBjUjFjEVfVTfBRDEjzOjDjIjBjSiJiEiUjPiUjZjQjFiJiEWfRBFeEi
EjDjNjOffEjWfRBFeEiPjSjEjOffEjWfRBFeEiUjSjHjUffffJjMnASzEjEjFjTjDXCEjzQjFjYjFjD
jVjUjFiBjDjUjJjPjOiHjFjUYfRBVTfBffnftOjNbjOn0AEJjOnASXCEXzHjHjFjUiMjJjTjUZfVXfC
RBEjzQjTjUjSjJjOjHiJiEiUjPiUjZjQjFiJiEgafRBFeMjUjBjSjHjFjUiMjBjZjFjSjTffffnffJj
PnASzBjDgbDXzFjDjPjVjOjUgcfVXfCnftJjQnASDAEjSfntnftajRbyjSn0ABgjSbyBn0ACJjTnAXz
PjCjBjDjLjHjSjPjVjOjEiMjBjZjFjSgdfjNfJjUnAEXzEjQjVjTjIgefVDfARBEXzIjHjFjUiJjOjE
jFjYgffEXzMjHjFjUiSjFjGjFjSjFjOjDjFhAfVXfCRBVEfEffnfffABnzBjFhBnbyBn0ABJjWnAEXg
efVDfyBRBCPEXgffEXhAfVXfyBRBVEfyBffnfnndBffAVEfEAVgbfDByBQAEXzGjIjBjTiLjFjZhCfV
XfCRBEjgafRBFeMjUjBjSjHjFjUiMjBjZjFjSjTffffbjan0AEJjanASTBEjUfntnftJjbnAEXzLjQj
VjUiQjSjPjQjFjSjUjZhDfVTfBRCEjWfRBFeEiQjSjQjSffEjWfRBFeEiJjUjNiJffffJjcnAEXVfVT
fBRDEjWfRBFeEiMjZjShAffEjWfRBFeEiPjSjEjOffEjWfRBFeEiUjSjHjUffffgjebyBn0ACJjfnAX
gdfjNfJkAnAEXgefVDfARBCIEXzKjHjFjUiJjOjUjFjHjFjShEfEjYfRBVTfBffRBEjWfRBFeEiJjUj
NiJffffnndBffABnhBnbyBn0ABJkDnAEXgefVDfyBRBEXhEfEjYfRBVTfyBffRBEjWfRBFeEiJjUjNi
JffffffZkHnAVDf0AFE4E0AiAX4C0AiAD40BiAT4B0AiAgb4D0AiAAFAzUjHjFjUiTjFjMjFjDjUjFj
EiMjBjZjFjSjTiJjEjYhFAkIMkKbyBn0ABakYbkZn0AHJkZnASXBEjzQiBjDjUjJjPjOiEjFjTjDjSj
JjQjUjPjShGfntnftJkanASTCEjUfntnftJkbnAEXzIjQjVjUiJjOjEjFjYhHfVTfCRCEjWfRBFeEiM
jZjShAffQCfVzDjJjEjYhIfGVEfAffJkcnAEXzMjQjVjUiSjFjGjFjSjFjOjDjFhJfVXfBRCEjWfRBF
eEjOjVjMjMffVTfCffOkdbken0AEJkenASzTjJjEjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOiNjPjEjJjGjJjFjShKDEj
gafRBFeRjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOiNjPjEjJjGjJjFjSffnftJkfnASzXjJjEjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOiN
jPjEjJjGjJjFjSiUjZjQjFhLEEjgafRBFeVjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOiNjPjEjJjGjJjFjSiUjZjQjFff
nftJlAnASzQjJjEjBjEjEiUjPiTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOhMFEjgafRBFeOjBjEjEiUjPiTjFjMjFjDjUj
JjPjOffnftJlBnAEXVfVXfBRDVhKfDVhLfEVhMfFffACzBhehNVEfAnndAnJlDnAEXzKjQjVjUiCjPj
PjMjFjBjOhOfVXfBRCEjWfRBFeEiNjLiWjTffVzHjWjJjTjJjCjMjFhPfHffJlEnAEjzNjFjYjFjDjV
jUjFiBjDjUjJjPjOhQfRDEjWfRBFeEjTjMjDjUffVXfBXzCiOiPhRfjzLiEjJjBjMjPjHiNjPjEjFjT
hSfffAVEf0AXJfVhIfGByBQAIE40BiAhK4D0AiAX4B0AiAhL4E0AiAhM4F0AiAhP4B0AhAT4C0AiAhI
40BhACGABAlGDJBnASDyBEjhFfnfnftJDnASzKjNjZiSjFjTjPjVjSjDjFhTyBCPCPnXJfVDfyBePjE
jJjBjMjPjHjbhAjUjFjYjUhahAhHnnne2lSChAiMjBjZjFjSjThAiTjFjMjFjDjUjFjEhHhMhAjQjSj
FjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhNhRhMhAhNhRidhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjSjJjH
jIjUhHhMKJJJJJjDjPjOjUjSjPjMjThahAiQjBjOjFjMjbhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjDj
PjMjVjNjOhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjSjJjHjIjUhHhMKJJJJJJJJhAhAjQjSjFj
GjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhShVhQhMhAhNhRidhMKJJJJJJjUjYjUhahAiHjSjPjVjQjbhAjPjSjJj
FjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMKJJJJJJJjMjBjCjFjMhahAiTjUjBjUjJjDiUjFjYjUhAjbjU
jFjYjUhahHiUjFjYjUhahAhHjdKJJJJJJJjJjOjQjVjUhahAiFjEjJjUiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhah
HhHhMhAjDjIjBjSjBjDjUjFjSjThahAhShYhMhAjBjDjUjJjWjFhajUjSjVjFjdKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJJ
jSjCjVjUjUjPjOjThahAiHjSjPjVjQjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahHjSjPjXhHhMKJJJJJJJjMj
BjCjFjMhahAiTjUjBjUjJjDiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiNjPjEjFhahAhHjdKJJJJJJJjBjQjQjF
jOjEhahAiSjBjEjJjPiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiBjQjQjFjOjEhHhMhAjWjBjMjVjFhajUj
SjVjFjdKJJJJJJJjQjSjFjQjFjOjEhahAiSjBjEjJjPiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiQjSjFjQ
jFjOjEhHjdKJJJJJJJjSjFjQjMjBjDjFhahAiSjBjEjJjPiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiSjFj
QjMjBjDjFhHjdKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJjdKJJJJJjCjVjUjUjPjOjThahAiHjSjPjVjQjbhAjPjSjJjFjOj
UjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAKJJJJJJjPjLifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUhah
HiPiLhHjdhMKJJJJJJjDjBjOjDjFjMifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiDjBjOjDj
FjMhHjdhMKJJJJJjdKJJJJjdnftgXbyBn0ABOYbZn0ACJZnASzIjNjZiXjJjOjEjPjXhUyBEjzGiXjJ
jOjEjPjXhVfRBVhTfyBftnftOgbbgdn0AHJgdnASGyBXzEjUjFjYjUhWfXzFjJjOjQjVjUhXfXGfXzI
jDjPjOjUjSjPjMjThYfVhUfyBnftJgenASzGjBjQjQjFjOjEhZyBXzFjWjBjMjVjFhafXhZfXzIjSjC
jVjUjUjPjOjThbfXhYfVhUfyBnftJgfnASzHjQjSjFjQjFjOjEhcyBXhafXhcfXhbfXhYfVhUfyBnft
JhAnASHyBXhafXHfXhbfXhYfVhUfyBnftOhEbhFn0ACJhFnASzUjQjSjFjQjQjFjOjEiBjQjQjFjOjE
ifjMjBjCjFjMhdyBneIiBjQjQjFjOjEjFjEftJhGnASKyBneGjBjQjQjFjOjEftAVhZfyBOhHbhIn0A
CJhInASzTjQjSjFjQjFjOjEiBjQjQjFjOjEifjMjBjCjFjMheyBneJiQjSjFjQjFjOjEjFjEftJhJnA
SKyBneHjQjSjFjQjFjOjEftAVhcfyBbhLn0ACJhLnASheyBneIiSjFjQjMjBjDjFjEftJhMnASKyBne
HjSjFjQjMjBjDjFftJhPnAEXzOjTjVjTjQjFjOjEiIjJjTjUjPjSjZhffXNfjOfRCFehfibiLiBiNid
hAiMjBjZjFjSjThAiSjFjOjBjNjFjShAiTjDjSjJjQjUhAhIiMjFjBjSjOhAjNjPjSjFhahAjIjUjUj
QhahPhPjCjMjPjHhOjLjBjNhYhYhOjDjPjNhJFehIjQjSjFjQjFjOjEiBjQjQjFjOjEhIjTjFjMjFjD
jUjFjEiMjBjZjFjSjThMhAjUjYjUhMhAjNjPjEjFhJffJhQnAEjBfRCVDfyBFcfffACzChdhdiAEXzE
jTjIjPjXiBfVhUfyBnfnndBnAChNXJfVDfyBnndBbyhan0ABJhanAEjzFjBjMjFjSjUiCfRBFehHiFj
SjSjPjSKiQjMjFjBjTjFhAjTjFjMjFjDjUhAjNjPjSjFhAjUjIjBjOhAjPjOjFhAjMjBjZjFjSffABn
hBnbyBn0ABJhdnAEjiCfRBjhBfffAKG4D0AiAD40BiAK4I0AiAhT4B0AiAhU4C0AiAhZ4E0AiAhc4F0
AiAhd4H0AiAhe4J0AiAH4G0AiAAKACByB
```

Comment: have you heard the expression 'teach by example'? :)

Comment: @Vincent :) I was actually just gonna write to fedorov that I initially thought about editing his answer to show how I would have done it, but it turned out to be such a huge edit that I decided to post it as my own answer.

Comment: Hi @Joonas, thank you so much!  I'm using layrs and it works great.  I'm quite new for using ps and ai.  Actually I'm an app programmer, but very interested in UI design.  I'm very interested in the scripts you posted.  At the beginning, I thought there should be someway to write code in ps, just like we can write VBA for MS office, but I didn't find the right way.  Your answer is inspiration for me, now I'm reading http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/25/introduction-to-photoshop-scripting/ as a start to learn this.

Comment: Hi @Joonas, do you have some suggested tutorials link for learning scripts in PS for the beginner?

Comment: @Vigor A good way to learn is to basically develop a need for something... like a need to rename layers. Googling for small snippets makes sense. E.g. You don't know how to do something, so google "Photoshop javascript selected layer", paste the example into your code and run it to see what happens. The [CC javascript reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf) can also be used for that, to some extend. Sometimes you can find useful stuff in the sample scripts.

Answer (score 0):

try these plugins.
http://www.renamy.com/
http://madebyvadim.com/layrs/

More plugins on madebyvadim.tumblr.com

Comment: Hi hellofedorov, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please explain in your answer why the plugin answers the question? In that way, your answer remains valuable in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and enjoy the site!

Comment: I think the gif on the site renamy.com shows and tells all. 
But I will take note of your remark.
Thanks

Comment: While what @Vincent says is true, it's difficult advice to follow in these cases. When your answer points to a plugin or application, you can't can't exactly upload them to stackexchange for safekeeping and if you can't download the extension anymore, a description in the answer might be a bit unnecessary anyways. --- "This extension is super cool. It does everything you've ever wanted." **User clicks the link to download it** "404".

Comment: Either way, I would have have included images of each extension and listed features, personal opinions and how much they cost or if they are free. --- I would probably have mentioned **scripts** as well, since at least you can paste in the code in SE. --- The Layrs Control extension is a collection of scripts, so the original script could have been mentioned. Also, Captain Awesome has pretty good "Group layer renaming" script. There probably are some other ones that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

An ActionScript snippet that will do what you want on the sublayers of your currently selected group layer.  Simply iterates over each layer in the group, and replaces text in the sublayer's name.  I ran my script in the ExtendScript Toolkit.

```
for (var    i = 0 ;
            i < app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers.length ;
            i++)
{
    var LAYER       = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers[i];
    var VISIBLE     = LAYER.visible;
       // replace 'abc' with 'def'
    LAYER.name      = LAYER.name.replace("abc","def");
    LAYER.visible   = VISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful this script to rename Photoshop layers automatically, you can find it here: http://www.sosfactory.com/batch-rename-photoshop-layers/

Comment: You should disclose that you own the website, just to make it clear that you're not spamming us with self-promotion.

Comment: If you can, copy the parts of the example you provide as a link into the answer so that it can be self-contained. This way, if the site provided is removed, the answer will still be valid.

Comment: @Luciano this is a public forum and this is a script that fits exactly with the question the user made. I don't see how this could be considered Spam.

Comment: Then add the script here or explain how to do it. Read this: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1055/16316

Comment: @luciano so what is the problem in linking to my own stuff when I have spend time and effort to create a resource that I share for free? Is this really such a big deal? If so... please, report my comment as spam, if my message gets deleted I definitively don't fit in this community.

Comment: Calm down. I did not flag your answer as spam, I'm merely telling you what to do to not get flagged. READ the link I posted earlier, you'll find this : _Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, *you must disclose your affiliation in your answers*._