# Layers to png with names in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, batch-processing

I am looking for a way to export all layers (nested too if possible) of a PSD file to png. But just the layer, with it's current size, not in the document size, with background or other layers.

I tried the script in this answer: [Batch export Photoshop layers to individual PNG files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process/16920#16920)

but it generates the png with background and the size of the document.

I need that if my file has buttons or small things, they export with the current layer size and name to png.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe these could help. [Adobe generator (CC and CC 2014  )](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html), [Cut & SLice me (CS6 and CC)](http://www.cutandslice.me/), standalone app for mac [Slicy](http://macrabbit.com/slicy/) I've used it with psd files saved in CS3 – CC 2014.

Comment: Thanks! Slicy is the best choice I guess..it just needs the .png in layers. Cut & Slice me is great and free but I need to re-arrange like 30 files not only by name but also grouping more than 100 layers per file. Thanks joonas

Comment: Cynthia Lara, my favorite is Slicy, even over the native assets generator, but just so you know, these are not the only options. There are like at least 5 other, paid, extensions that I know of. I just didn't want to write a huge list in the comment.

Comment: Oh, as far as the renaming goes... [there's this question / answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/how-do-i-rename-multiple-selected-layers-in-photoshop-cc/36963#36963). As far as the free ones go, I'd recommend Group Layer Renaming script (the one with orange background). Especially if you set a hotkey to launch the script.

Comment: wow so you are a man full of answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Photoshop CC or CC 2014, you might be best off using the native Adobe Generator. In the future, it's going to have svg export too. Currently that's experimental feature.

- [Adobe Generator](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html) - **Free** ( Assuming that you have Photoshop CC or CC 2014 )

**List of "asset" export plugins:**

- [Cut & Slice me](http://www.cutandslice.me/) - **Free**
- [Breezy](http://www.breeezyplugin.com/) - **Free**
- [Slicy](http://macrabbit.com/slicy)
- [PNG Hat](http://pnghat.madebysource.com/)
- [Slash](http://photoshopmonkeys.com/)
- [Png express](http://www.pngexpress.com/)
- [Lasagna](https://gumroad.com/products/qXEE)
- [Export Pro](https://creativemarket.com/diegomonzon/6350-Export-Pro-Photoshop-CS6-CC-Plugin)

<sub>I'm not very fond of Adobe Generator because sometimes, even if you haven't enabled it and you save a .psd document that has extensions in the layer names, such as mylayer.jpg, it'll try to save the assets ...and they come out corrupted or something. It can be fully disabled through the preferences though, so it's not an issue when I'm using Slicy instead.</sub>

The only ones I have used and would recommend are: Adobe Generator, Slicy and Cut & Slice Me. Although I'm not the biggest fan of the way you mark layers with Cut & Slice Me.

Comment: I'll just put this here as well http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36955/2332

Comment: Thanks, I am trying Slicy and seems to be the best for it´s simplicity-using a renamer script for adding the .png to the layer names it's the perfect tool for me at the moment.

Comment: @CynthiaLara Slicy is great. I also like that you see previews of the images and you can drag and drop from slicy to finder, which is great for quick exports, where the auto-save is unnecessary. It occurred to me that [you might be interested in the last section of this answer here.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38037/2332) (Below: Exporting layer dimensions / styles to css)

Comment: wow I will definitely check on it later :D right now my needs are not explicitly web related (png needs) but I will bookmark this for future reference on webdesign! Thanks for your kind support!!

Answer (score -2):

[Single-click layer exporting in Photoshop](http://viget.com/inspire/single-click-layer-exporting-in-photoshop) hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! Please provide a summary of what is in the link. We aim to be a site where solutions are found directly, as links often dies.