# Is there a fast way to clean up empty layers and folders in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a very large document, and along the way I have made a lot of changes and new layers. I have a tons of layers and groups and I'm now sitting and organize everything manually.

Is there are fast way to clean up unused and empty layers?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 8):

The easiest and best method would be this:

In yours Layers tab click to the **Filters** which says Name, in the dropdown select **Attribute**

Next to the filter there will be another dropdown where you need to select **Empty** to reveal the empty layers.

[image]

Enjoy

Answer (score 5):

While Alex's answer should be enough, here are some other options for layer organizing.

- [Layrs control extension](http://madebyvadim.com/layrs/) - Free ( basically collection of scripts )
- [PSD cleaner](http://psdcleaner.madebysource.com/) - ~$20 In some respects this is a lot like a checlist that asks you to take action, but isn't necessarily fully automated.
- Also, the fly-out menu in the Layers panel has an option to `Delete hidden layers`.
- There are also [more layer renaming options](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/how-do-i-rename-multiple-selected-layers-in-photoshop-cc/36963#36963). Although, if you find Layrs control otherwise useful, its layer renaming script is pretty extensive.