# Photoshop animation: How to render each layer to a separate file at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, photoshop-scripting, animate

Is there a way to render each separate layer in Photoshop to a separate file? I have a character from Fuse and I want to render it in X positions. I don't want to click 'render' for every new layer, of course. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: I have a right answer here: Render Video ->  Photoshop Image Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**Menu File** > **Scripts** > **Export Layers to Files**...

- Choose a destination, file name and file type:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for comment. Unfortunetly that's not a solution, I tried that before (and it's File -> Export -> Layers to Files in new CC). I don't want to save 'undone' 3d object, I want to render the object, and I would like to do this automatically for every layer.

Answer (score 0):

### Make Layers Image Assets

You could turn on [Image Assets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html) and name all your layers with their desired output parameters.

If you have many layers, you could run a [script or action](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/how-do-i-rename-multiple-selected-layers-in-photoshop-cc) to rename them based on your variables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for comment! I just found a right answer Render Video -> Photoshop Image Sequence).

Comment: Glad you found an answer :) If you found my answer useful, please feel free to upvote it!